# Can't netboot a PowerMac G4

Tags: mac-mini, g4, netboot

I'm trying to install Debian (by net booting off tftp) on my old Mac Mini G4. I get into OpenFirmware (<kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> after boot chime) and enter:

```
boot my.mac.ip.address,yaboot
```

After I hit enter this appears for a split second:

[image: .]

Then I am stuck at this screen:

[image: .]